# automatically set vim ctags based on working directory

Tags: file, vim, project, ctags

I want to automatically set vim tags based on what project i am currently working on. For example given directory /home/user/project of this structure:

```
├── src
│   ├── main/...
│   └── test/...
├── tags
```

I want vim to automatically detect that it is in this directory or one of it's subdirectories and run command

```
set tags=/home/user/project/tags
```

to set proper tags.

Is this even possible? Is this even a good idea or am i overcomplicating things and there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually looking  for an answer for a long time and found it within 30 mins of posting this question eh.

```
set tags=tags;/
```

solves the problem

Comment: You might want `tags;~`—if you dont have a tags file, your answer will search all the way to root, while that searches only to home directory. With fugitive and some git hooks I use `.git/tags;~`